# The type 'CellValuePresenter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvvm

> Error  CS0012  The type 'CellValuePresenter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.2, Version=13.2.20132.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'

```
public void NavigateToView(TextEditorValidationRun validationRun)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as TextEditorViewModel;
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        return;
    }


    if(viewModel.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId !=validationRun.LanguageId)
    {
        viewModel.SelectedLanguage = viewModel.Languages.First(x => x.LanguageId == validationRun.LanguageId); 
    }

    stringsDataGrid.ActiveDataItem = viewModel.TranslatableStrings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TextId.Equals(validationRun.TextId));
    if(stringsDataGrid.ActiveDataItem!=null)
    {
        string fieldName = stringsDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields[3].Name;
        DataRecord dr = stringsDataGrid.Records.DataPresenter.GetRecordFromDataItem(stringsDataGrid.ActiveDataItem, false);
        stringsDataGrid.ActiveCell = dr.Cells.Where(t => t.Field.Name == fieldName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (stringsDataGrid.ActiveCell != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                CellValuePresenter cellPresenter = CellValuePresenter.FromCell(dr.Cells[i]);
                if (cellPresenter != null)
                {
                    ErrorNavigationAnimation.HighlightErrorField(cellPresenter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is? The error is explaining exactly what you have to do

Comment: You are running a project without a .dll files of Infragistics component.